# Where does the Item tickbox come from

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, detailsview

I currently have a DetailsView (used to be a Formview, but that is a nogo with Masterpage and ObjectDataSource).

Somehow there is an "Item [ ]" (tickbox) in the graphics that I can't find in the source.
It is graphically found after the "Kommentar:" and before the "Dato:"

```
                <asp:DetailsView ID="dv_InsertComment" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataSourceID="ods_InsertComment"
                    HeaderText="Kommentar:">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dato:">
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="dNow" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>'></asp:Label>
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Konto" Visible="false">
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbAccountIns" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kommentar:">
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbCommentIns" runat="server" Rows="3" Columns="50" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status:">
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusList" runat="server" DataSourceID="ods_StatusOptions"
                                    DataTextField="name">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fremnotering:">
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DateBox ID="dFuture" runat="server" AllowNullDate="true" />
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Indsæt kommentar" CommandName="Insert" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

Ontop of that the parameter list requires a "!" after NewDate. Aka it requires: "employee, Account, Comment, Type, Status, NewDate, !."

```
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods_InsertComment" runat="server" InsertMethod="InsertComment"
                    TypeName="OurClient.Host.CommentsBLL" SelectMethod="GetNothing">
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="employee" SessionField="employee" DbType="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Account" DbType="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" DbType="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Type" DefaultValue="0" DbType="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Status" DbType="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="NewDate" DbType="DateTime" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I'm thinking if I remove the Item and tickbox, the "!" parameter will go away too. But if it is not there how do I remove it?

I have removed the entire `<Fields></Fields>` just to have only the Item [] remaining. I moved the `DefaultMode="Insert"` out and the Item [] went grey (not clickable). As I said in the beginning - the `DetailsView` is a solution instead of a `FormView`.

Before you ask the `GetNothing` is a requirement, it must have a `SelectMethod` defined. Can't compile it unless it's there.

Solution: `AutoGenerateRows="False"` on `<asp:detailsview ....>`

How did I spot that one? I went to the aspx in question, changed to the Split view and continued to analyse what controls were actually present. I kinda stumbled over the Auto Generate checkbox.

Comment: <tr>
   <td>Item</td><td><span title="Item" class="aspNetDisabled"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$dv_InsertComment$ctl01" id="ContentPlaceHolder2_dv_InsertComment_ctl01"></span></td>
  </tr>

Comment: Well, from the place where it is: before Dato: and After Kommentar: somehow your aspx is not consistent with the html generatged (but you knew that already). have you tried to comment out all the templatefields and adding them ony by one?

Comment: I even removed all of them, incl the fields definition. Still the Item remained. If I remove the DetailsView the Item dissapears too. Somehow it seems linked to the DetailsView and not the individual fields. Confirmed, I've just commented out each field both expanding the selection and then retracting the selection. `<%-- --%>`. The Item remained throughout. Our graphics guy has recently added the css, but that doesn't specify anything on FormView or DetailsView.

Comment: Solution: AutoGenerateRows="False"

Comment: That explains the name "ctl01" of the checkbox control. It automatically generated that column everytime. Well spotted. you should edit your question and add this solution to allow others to quickly see that. Very nice. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched the code-behind file?

Maybe the checkbox is injected?

The id of the checkbox is "ContentPlaceHolder2_dv_InsertComment_ctl01", that could be a control which was added dynamically.

Check your code-behind file for any string like "InsertComment" or "dv_" or "_dv", etc. and have a look.

I'm only guessing off course.

Comment: Not found. The closest I get to that mindspin is - I transfer the Account number from another control over to the comments blog control. `            // Setting the Account number
            TextBox tbAcc = (TextBox)dv_InsertComment.FindControl("tbAccountIns");
            tbAcc.Text = account.Text;
` (account in the input parameter (Label))

Comment: That is strange alright. Given the checkbox is not in the design but shows up in the rendered markup it would seem to be a dynamic addtion. Is there any "CheckBox" type decleration in the code behind at all? I mean, there must be code to read the checkboxes value at some point or another?

Comment: I don't use any CheckBox in the entire solution. Not even a "Remember my login".

Comment: wow, that's very strange indeed, the checkbox *<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$dv_InsertComment$ctl01" id="ContentPlaceHolder2_dv_InsertComment_ctl01">* must be coming from somewhere. Sorry for not having been able to help more.

Comment: I'm assuming you are compiling and running the code and see the checkbox and not comparing the source code to a published version? I'm only asking because if you are comparing source code from version control to a published version instead, your source might not be the latest version or is later than the published one and the 2 simply don't match. Maybe a JavaScript is adding the checkbox somehwere?

Comment: I haven't written any Javascript for quite a number of years. I'm the solo developer and I'm viewing this on the VS2010 developer webserver. I don't use any of the MS auto tools, I do my own work.